# Can hydrogen be stored in the crystalline structure of ice?

Tags: crystals, hydrogen, ice, energy-storage

I recently read that when ice freezes to form hexagonal crystals, the space within the hexagon is in fact a vacuum. Could this space potentially be used to store burnable hydrogen gas? If so, would the hydrogen be released as the ice melts, or could it be extracted in some other way?

*Edit: Per PM 2Ring and John Rennie's comments, this state is called a [Clathrate Hydrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clathrate_hydrate). A rephrased question would be, "are clathrate hydrates a viable hydrogen storage mechanism?"*

Comment: Here's some relevant background info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clathrate_hydrate

Comment: Yes, see [hydrogen clathrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_clathrate) though I think is a chemistry question rather than a physics question.